# Fourier expansion of the complexified Gram series

Tags: special-functions, fourier-series

Consider the Riemann's R function, also known as the Gram series:
$$\text{R}(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\log x\right)^{k}}{kk!\zeta(k+1)}$$
Now consider the form:
$$\text{R}\left(e^{2\pi ix} \right )+\text{R}\left(e^{-2\pi ix} \right )$$
By the definition of $\text{R}(x)$ an easy calculation shows that:
$$\text{R}\left(e^{2\pi ix} \right )+\text{R}\left(e^{-2\pi ix} \right )=2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}\text{Ci}\left(\frac{2\pi x}{m}\right)$$
Where $\mu(m)$ is the $\text{M}\ddot{\text{o}}\text{bius}$ function. and $\text{Ci}(\cdot)$ is the cosine integral function. This function is clearly an even periodic function with period 1, and thus it has a Fourier series expansion of the form:
$$\text{R}\left(e^{2\pi ix} \right )+\text{R}\left(e^{-2\pi ix} \right )=a_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos(2\pi n x)$$
My question: i am having a trouble trying to find the constants $a_{n}$. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: But $Ci(x)$ is not periodic, by adding to it's argument I would naturally suspect that series gets smaller and is not therefore periodic. Clearly any function of $e^{-2\pi i x}$ is periodic but how do you get that series?

Comment: using the series expansion of $\text{Ci}$, and properties of $\mu(m)$ we get the equality.